# Get Raw HTML of Node in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have used `$("#parent").html()` to get the inner html of `#parent`, but how do I get the html of the parent itself?

The use case is, I grab an input node like this:

```
var field = $('input');
```

I would like to be able to get the raw html of that node (`<input type='text'>`) with something like `field.html()`, but that returns empty.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you could create add an JQuery function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
  return (s)
  ? this.before(s).remove()
  : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

so you could do this:

```
$('input').outerHTML();
```

or

```
$('input').outerHTML("new html");
```

thanks to http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Comment: Isn't `clone()` a problem due to event handlers?

Answer (score 10):

This question is very old, but there is now an easy solution:

```js
const html = $('input').prop('outerHTML');
```

Example string value of `html`:
**<input type="input">**

Fiddle with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/u0a1zkL1/3

And, the technique mentioned in Optimae's comment also works:

```js
const html = $('input')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: For anyone targeting the element that triggered an event, `var html = event.target.outerHTML` will also work.

Answer (score 8):

It's somewhat awkward to do:

```
var field = $("input"); // assuming there is but 1
var html = field.wrap("<div>").parent().html();
field.unwrap();
```

`html()` is analagous to `innerHTML`. There is no "standard" `outerHTML` method. The above wraps the element you want in a temporary element and gets the `innerHTML` of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var html = $('#parent')[0];
```

That will get the #parent node, then return the code of the first node returned (which will be the only one in this case).