# jquery selector to HTML Dom

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the outer HTML from a selected object with jQuery.

for example

```
$("#test.test_class")
```

to HTML string

```
<div id="test" class="test_class"></div>
```

Do anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: Assuming you want to construct html using selectors, Jquery selectors also has selectors like `:parent`, `:nth-child`, these cannot possibly be converted to HTML.

Comment: @LiJung was this your question, to get the html of an element?

Comment: @PSL yes it is, thanks! I've seen some comment below, I can't get what they mean also....Never mind. thanks again! You've solved my problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Raw HTML of Node in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779630/get-raw-html-of-node-in-jquery)

Comment: @simonzack Do you really read the answer link you posted? it is so inefficient as it wraps and unwraps. Take a look at this answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334115/create-html-tag-from-javascript-object/17334176#17334176

Comment: @PSL: I did read it, but they are still the exact same question, imo your answer to the other question you linked could be moved to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) property of the element to get the html string representation of the selected element. There is no other direct method/property in jquery which will give you this.

```
$("#test.test_class")[0].outerHTML;
```

or

```
$("#test.test_class").get(0).outerHTML;
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvDH5/)**

Comment: This doesn't provides answer to OP answer. OP wants to convert `selector` to HTML element

Comment: @Satpal Reading the question OP wants `$("#test.test_class")` to the html string. Doesn't this answer that?

Comment: @PSL: What Satpal said.

Comment: @PSL: I'm saying that I agree with Satpal, that your answer isn't relevant.

Comment: @simonzach it is relevant . Have a look at the example he provided on what he wants. Thats what I answered. How else do u interpret that.